# Horrible upload speed only on certain computers, can't seem to isolate issue, affecting exchange10

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, bandwidth

I'm having a very interesting/frustrating issue.

First off, I'm in the process of migrating Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010.  Everything appeared to be running swimmingly last evening after I set up the send connector on Exchange 10.  E-mails to every domain I sent to were received within seconds/minutes.

Today, when the users arrived and started pounding the network, we started having issues getting delays to gmail, aol, and a few minor domains..

A few various errors:
Connection dropped due to Connection reset
Connection dropped due to socket error

After a bit of troubleshooting I discovered that a speedtest from www.speakeasy.net/speedtest run from the exchange machine was showing 2.6mbit down, but the upload test would either time out, or register 0.0

From my machine, Ubuntu Maverick, the same occurs. Name: merlin (not on domain)

From a Windows 7 Ultimate machine, it gets a normal upload of about 2.5 Name: craig (not on domain)

From another Windows 7 Ultimate machine, (on domain), upload stalls.  Name: peter

From a windows xp machine (on domain), upload is 2.7. Name: adpbox

From three Windows Server 2003 boxes, some DCs some not, upload is 2.5-3.0 Names: exchserver(old exchange box,dc) remote1(app server), vault(file server, dc)

Another thing I'm noticing on affected PCs: Downloads start off normally at 300 or so kb from the average site, but then slow to a trickle of 5-6kb.

Results from speakeasy speedtest duplicated with other speed tests.

If anyone can offer any advice on further troubleshooting I can do, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an exchange issue. Has some network guy been doing maintenance on a switch somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest way to resolve this is to mirror the port with the outbound internet traffic or place a box inline and sniff the traffic. NTOP would be useful here but simple wireshark may be effective enough. You could rig up a laptop to do it temporarily at a time when there aren't too many lusers on the network.

Try to isolate whether its a DNS, bandwidth or packet loss issue.

Some tools that may assist:

- mtr : this can help you find where packet loss is occuring in the network, which router is responsible or whether its upstream
- ipperf : run some performance benchmarks between different spots in the network and see whether its just outgoing traffic affected or all traffic
- ethtool : try to work out whether its a layer 2 or layer 3 issue

From what you describe you believe what you have is exchange flooding the network. If you can remove exchange and prove this, great but I would keep an open mind it may be a combination of factors - e.g. exchange is pushing the network gear and its falling over beyond a certain point because its misconfigured.

Try to cross off the obvious: are you definately 1000/Full everywhere? Are uplinks being clogged? Are we simply using lots of bandwidth at a certain time of day when everyone else is - e.g. is the ISP to blame?

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, and I plan to put a box inline and use some of these tools for general bandwidth monitoring.  However! I believe I have discovered the issue using a different speedtest site.  I'm getting normal speeds from even the affected server to places like Boise, ID and Ashville, NC.  I'm getting little to no speed from Washington DC(right next door to us) and San Francisco.  I'm thinking that our ISP is to blame.  I still can't explain why Washington DC works swimmingly from other machines, but I'll definitely be e-mailing them straight away.